# How to know if a date range intersects with another date range in Java - Groovy

Tags: java, date, groovy

Scenario 1:

- R1 =  02/08/2018 - 20/08/2018
- R2 =  06/08/2018 - 29/08/2018

  ```
   R1   |--------------|
   R2          |---------------------|
  ```

Scenario 2:

- R1 =  02/08/2018 - 20/08/2018
- R2 =  31/08/2018 - 16/09/2018

  ```
   R1   |--------------|
   R2                     |---------------------|
  ```

There are two different date ranges, and I need to compare these ranges to find out if they intersect or not. For example, in the first scenario, the ranges intersect and in the second scenario they do not. The dates are in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

What is the best way to determine if they intersect or not using Java?

```
       def R1Initial = SDF.parse(u.effectiveStartDate.text())
       def R1End = SDF.parse(u.mdfSystemEffectiveEndDate.text())
       def R2Initial = SDF.parse(u.effectiveStartDate.text())
       def R2End = SDF.parse(u2.mdfSystemEffectiveEndDate.text())
       def intersects = ?????
```

Comment: @Jacob Not quite a duplicate, as that Question is language-agnostic. This Question is **language-specific, with Groovy & Java**. With Groovy, we have a specific solution supported by the language, as seen in [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710748/642706) by bdkosher.  In Java, we have a specific solution available to us in the *java.time* classes and *ThreeTen-Extra* project, as seen in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715319/642706). I looked for other Java-specific originals asking about overlapping date ranges, but did not find any. Hence my Answer and my up-votes.

Answer (score 4):

You can create [ranges of `LocalDate` instances in Groovy 2.5](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_ranges_code_upto_code_and_code_downto_code). Ranges (which extend Iterables) have an [`intersect` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#intersect(java.lang.Iterable)), which returns a collection of the overlapping days between two ranges. If the intersection is non-empty, you know that there is overlap:

```
import java.time.*

def r1 = (LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 2)..LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 20))
def r2 = (LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 6)..LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 29))

def overlap = r1.intersect(r2) // returns a list containing August 6th through August 20th
```

Comment: This work, but the method intersect with large date range costs too much.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by bdkosher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710748/642706) looks correct, taking advantage of a nifty feature in Groovy.

## `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`

If doing much work with date-ranges, you may find helpful the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

That class offers several methods for comparison: `abuts`, `contains`, `encloses`, `equals`, `intersection`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isConnected`, [`overlaps`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#overlaps-org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange-), `span`, and `union`.

```
LocalDateRange r1 = 
    LocalDateRange.of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2018, 8 , 2 ) , 
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , 8 , 20 ) 
    ) 
;
LocalDateRange r2 = LocalDateRange.of( LocalDate.of( 2018 , 8 , 6 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , 8 , 29 ) ) ;

boolean overlaps = r1.overlaps( r2 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).